# MySQL text field default values and version differences

Tags: mysql

In developing my board software, I was informed of a problem with MySQL 5.1.36 regarding text fields and default values. This occurs when registering a new user, which is the first thing done after installing.

The users table has, among various other things, a signature field defined as "TEXT NOT NULL". When registering, this field is not specified in the INSERT query's field list. On my local testing/development server running MySQL 5.1.30 this works fine. On my live server running MySQL 5.0.91 this also works. But then this tester comes up to me and says that it doesn't work on *his* testing server running 5.1.36, the error message complaining that the query must specify a default value.

There are a lot of TEXT fields in play here. My original plan is to detect MySQL 5.1.36 and have the installer decline to run, but only if the behavior is unique to 5.1.36. Does .37 or higher do the same? Did I just miss something?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier just to set the default field values to `''` (empty string)? Then you don't need to worry about MySQL versions.

Comment: Because there are a lot of text fields, like I said.

Comment: but you only set up the table definition once, so trying to avoid setting the field default seems a false economy, even if there are umpteen text fields in multiple tables.  The other possibility, rather than detecting MySQL versions, is just to write your insert queries with an empty string for each text field.  But that *is* a lot more work.

Comment: The funny part is that, if I remember correctly, I can't just specify "" as the default value in the table definition in the first place...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to give Default Text like 'not updated' to text type in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886364/how-to-give-default-text-like-not-updated-to-text-type-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just change all your text columns to allow `NULL` ?  Mysql doesn't let you specify `DEFAULT` for text/blob columns.

Answer (score 7):

This behavior is ***not*** unique to 5.1.36, In fact I think it's premature to assume that the MySQL version is relevant to this issue at all.

I recommend that you check which SQL_MODE is being used:

```
select @@SQL_MODE;
```

If the SQL_MODE is empty, then I would expect the insert to succeed (with a warning) in all of the versions you listed.

If the SQL_MODE is more strict, such as `TRADITIONAL` or `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`, then I would expect the insert to fail in all of the versions you listed with the error: `ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'your_field' doesn't have a default value`

Possible fixes:

1) Change the columns to explicitly allow NULL values:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY COLUMN your_column TEXT NULL;
```

2) Force the SQL_MODE to ''. The best way to do this is to set it in my.cnf and restart mysql, but you can also set it at the MySQL prompt for testing:

```
SET SESSION SQL_MODE = '';
```

Comment: You are a god walking among men. Thank you for this, it saved me after a day's worth of struggling. :D +1