# how to set default value for text type in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `te` (
  `id` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `Aboutus` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here Table 'te' consist 4 fields id, name, address, Aboutus, Aboutus is optional means how can i update default text to the Profile in db , by phpmyadmin sql

Comment: Do you want to do the same from webpage or what?

Comment: web page but is there any way to do default text for that field like as define for integers @Ullas

Comment: That means if the user doesn't fill that field, the default text should update in the database rite?

Comment: No **BLOB/TEXT columns  can't have a default value** you may need to create a trigger

Comment: Yep just as @MKhalidJunaid said. Found it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466872/why-cant-a-text-column-have-a-default-value-in-mysql

Comment: ya..@Ullas when user entered the text should be update

Comment: how to create trigger? @MKhalidJunaid

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have changed not null to null for about us field

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `te` (
  `id` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `Aboutus` text NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is your trigger `BEFORE INSERT`

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON `te`
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.`Aboutus` = CASE WHEN NEW.Aboutus IS NULL THEN 'Not Updated' ELSE NEW.Aboutus END
;
```

Insert without `Aboutus`

```
INSERT INTO `te` (`id`, `name`, `address`) 
VALUES (1, 'name', 'address') ;
```

Insert with `Aboutus`

```
INSERT INTO `te` (`id`, `name`, `address`, `Aboutus`) 
VALUES (2, 'name', 'address', 'Aboutus') ;
```

Insert by passing null `Aboutus`

```
INSERT INTO `te` (`id`, `name`, `address`, `Aboutus`) 
VALUES (3, 'name', 'address', null) ;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee3ef/1)

**Edit** As [**@garethD**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048425/garethd) pointed a case for update scenario,you also need another trigger on `BEFORE UPDATE` so if null appears in update then aboutus should be updated as `Not Updated`

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON `te`
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.`Aboutus` = CASE WHEN NEW.Aboutus IS NULL THEN 'Not Updated' ELSE NEW.Aboutus END
;

UPDATE te
SET AboutUs = NULL;
```

### [Demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/226e7/1)

Comment: +1, It will also need a trigger to handle updates, to stop someone running [`UPDATE te SET AboutUs = NULL;`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aec4/1)

Comment: @GarethD thanks for pointing on such a mistake i haven't really thought regarding update scenario thanks again

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 16.04:

How to disable strict mode in MySQL 5.7:

Edit file /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

If below line exists in mysql.cnf

```
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Then Replace it with

```
sql_mode='MYSQL40'
```

Otherwise

Just add below line in mysqld.cnf

```
sql_mode='MYSQL40'
```

This resolved problem.